# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'

Tags: java, spring

When I try to use "Maven Package" in a Spring Boot project, it runs the default-test but it fails, send alert `URL must start with 'jdbc'`

I use this on `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url= ${DB_URL}
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=12345
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa-hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I declared `DB_URL` in IntelliJ environment variables

[image]

Comment: Please check [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your question must be clear and have enough details (what research for you done so far? what have you tried?) so that the community can help. Thanks!

Comment: He actually gives the error, shows what he tried... It is a decent question, you get an up-vote from me. Maybe give it some more structure though, so the problem is a little more clear. And change the placeholder. XD (enter image description here) This will make the question more useful to others. Welcome to SO, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In intellij you can configure these properties via `VM options` rather than `Environment variables`

Add this to `VM options`.

```
-DDB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/biblioteca
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to run the maven commands in terminal, like this:

```
mvn -DDB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/biblioteca test
```

or

```
mvn -DDB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/biblioteca clean install
```

Maven is not aware of the environment variables so you will have to pass them into the command line.